# Удобный PL SQL редактор

Tags: sql, oracle, ide, plsql

Расскажите пожалуйста, кто какими инструментами пользуется для работы с PL/SQL кодом? 
Уже давно использую для подобных задач SQL Developer компании Oracle, но в нем многие вещи не устраивают: отсутствие нормальной подсветки кода, постоянно "отваливающиеся" connections, ну и еще много мелочей.

Может есть лучшие средства (программы), облегчающие жизнь разработчику?

*P.S. Желательно free products, поскольку рабочая станция корпоративная*

Comment: используйте toad

Comment: @jmu платный, не ?

Comment: dbForge удобный, но он вроде не для коммерческого использования

Comment: @sonniy раньше был платный только для коменческого использования. кроме того у него есть бесплатный плагин к eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо Oracle SQL Developer лично у вас как-то нестабильно работает. Он очень простой и удобный, не то что всякие PL/SQL Developer и TOAD, где куча ненужного барахла.

Продолжайте использовать **Oracle SQL Developer**!

Answer (score 3):

Пользуюсь vim - работает на всех платформах, всё настраивается. Если что-то не работает можно поправить потому, что весь функционал в плагинах или скриптах. 
В стандартной поставке имеются самые необходимые плагины - подсветка синтаксиса, автоиндент и т.п. - для работы с pl/sql.

Answer (score 2):

Использую NOTEPAD++. Настраиваемая подсветка и куча полезных мелочей.
[NP++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: И что, им можно подключиться к серверу БД и выполнять запросы?

Comment: @msi, вообще говоря - можно, но не очень удобно - там есть вызов внешней программы на открытый файл - можно подключить вызов sqlcmd. В остальном - только как редактором.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь SQLTools. Он бесплатный.
Сравнить не с чем, т.к. другими не пользовался.

Answer (score 1):

На работе использую PL/SQL Developer. Он платный, но намного лучше SQL Developer. На предыдущем месте использовали SQL Navigator. Тоже платный. Обе программы гораздо, намного лучше SQL Developer. SQL Developer по сравнению с ними полное разочарование.

От безысходности можно и SQL Developer обойтись, но лучше попробовать что-то другое. Очень советую.

Работал как-то в Oracle Forms - хреновенькая такая программа для разработки форм для взаимодействия с Oracle. Потом делали интерфейсы и некоторую логику на Delphi с использованием OCI для Oracle - небо и земля. Складывается впечатление, что в Oracle основные силы разработчиков брошены на разработку серверной части, у них это неплохо получается. С клиентской у них конкретные проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее популярными у нас были TOAD и PL/SQL Developer - обе платные.

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатный для некоммерческого использования [`DBForge`](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/), попробуйте посмотреть, но лично я использую `SQL Developer`.