# Посоветуйте IDE для работы в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ide

Начинаю только знакомится с Oracle и как я понял после установи батарейки в комплект не входят.

Какие в природе существуют IDE для работы с данной СУБД?

В приоритете конечно же бесплатные или те, где есть бесплатная версия для личного пользования, а потом уже платные решения.

Ранее, я работа с MS SQL через MS Management Studio, хотелось бы что-нибудь похожее под Oracle.

Comment: ничего лучше PLSQL Developer под Oracle не видел

Comment: @Viktorov , хм... Она платная или халява на 30 дней=(

Comment: В коробке только SQLPlus и SqlDeveloper. Первoe не есть IDE, второе слабовато для работы. На enSO обсуждались [альтернативы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286091/is-there-a-good-alternative-to-sqlplus-for-oracle) и мнения там очень расходятся. Как я думаю, вас будет ожидать некоторое разочарование после MS Management Studio.

Comment: @0xdb, мдя... Похоже, что даже визуализатора планов в виде схемы выполнения нету из коробки...

Comment: [dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/oracle/studio/).

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть в сторону Aqua Data Studio(платная). Я пока еще сам с ней не разобрался, но зато она вроде как умеет нормально дружить с Git'ом. И поддерживает большое количество баз данных

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer'а вполне хватает

Comment: Я с Oracle SQL Developer работаю лет 5 и мне более чем хватает. В разное время пробовал ради интереса TOAD, PL\SQL Developer, DBForge, EMS SQL Manager, Embarcadero Rapid SQL - каких-то преимуществ не увидел. Памяти только он потребляет прилично, если запущен пару недель.

Comment: Да, забыл напомнить, похожая [тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/202151/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-pl-sql-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) уже была, почему то  закрыли.

Answer (score 6):

Начните с того, что лежит в коробке:

- *SQL*Plus*: не IDE, но для управления БД необходимо. Большинство вопросов и ответов по Oracle используют его в примерах.
- *Sql Developer*: IDE уступающее по функционалу платным, но для освоения вполне хватит.

Только после того, как освоитесь, приступайте к выбору.

Бесплатные:

- [dbForge](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkZHTBRCBARIsAMbXLhEXo-h3xLihXxXf7mRJdOOnAlNZTDneF7ihbsO1zFt2WilacfUcc6gaAlfpEALw_wcB)
- [TOra](https://github.com/tora-tool/tora/wiki)
- [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/datagrip/)
- [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) + [dbext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356)

Платные:

- [ТОАД](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/#Features)
- [PL/SQL Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL_Developer)

Много рассказывать о каждом продукте в отдельности не имеет смысла, т.к будет базироваться на субъективном мнении, лучше по возможности пробовать.

Возможно поможет [сравнение различных IDE](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-sql-ide-comparison/).

Comment: о! благодаря вашему ответу я узнал о новых (для) меня бесплатных IDE...

Comment: @MaxU не удивительно, если фирма щедра на лицензии ;)

Comment: Пожалуй, пора сюда добавить [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/datagrip/). Она еще далека от совершенства,  но уже можно пробовать и работать

Comment: @Viktorov Спасибо, добавил

Answer (score 5):

На мой взгляд варианта только два:

- Из платного - [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html).
- Из freeware - [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.htm).

Comment: По-моему стоит упомянуть [Toad for Oracle](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/#Features) - как один из лучших платных IDE для Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Среди платных можно добавить [SQL Navigator](https://www.quest.com/products/sql-navigator/)

А вот насчет [сравнения различных IDE](https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-sql-ide-comparison/) где нет продуктов Quest, наводит на мысли, что указанная статья может быть не совсем "честной".

Comment: Почему вы решили, что там нет продуктов  Quest? А под н. 1 в линейке платных?