# Бесплатный аналог Sql Assistant для Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть ли какие-нибудь бесплатные аналоги Sql Assistant для Oracle или IDE с похожей особенностью?

В этой программе меня привлекает кодогенерация, вводишь JOIN и это расширение отображает все возможные связи на основании метаданных(PK,FK), так же предлагает связи на основании колонок с одинаковыми именами.

Другими словами, не нужно держать в голове структуру БД.

Comment: Скорее всего вы повторяете ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773400/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-ide-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-oracle/773592#773592). Все IDE это делают,  включая Sql Developer в коробке. Или нужен имеенно отдельный продукт?

Comment: @0xdb, хм... Надо потестить значит IDE. Я привык, что в MS SQL Management Studio этого не было из коробки.

Comment: Ну да, как я уже там ответил, попробуйте сначало что в коробке. Потом определитесь. Sql Developer, например, хоть и не перфект, но может всё, что вы спрашиваете в 3-х вопросах.